# Como combinar 2 o mas bases de datos tipo tibble en R?

Tags: r

Las diferentes incognitas son dos:

1) Tengo dos bases de datos diferente tipo tibble, se desea unir dos tibbles en uno solo pero la verdad he buscado por todo lado y nada que me dan un resolucion de este problema, el ejemplo es:

```
df1_tibble
 x y z
 1 2 3
 2 3 NA
 3 4 5
 4 5 6
 5 6 NA

df2_tibble
 a b c
 1 2 3
 2 3 4
 3 4 5
 4 5 6
 5 6 7
```

Y lo que se quiere como resultado es:

```
 a  b  c   x  y  z
 1  2  3   1  2  3
 2  3  NA  2  3  4
 3  4  5   3  4  5
 4  5  6   4  5  6
 5  6  NA  5  6  7
```

2) Seria lo mismo anterior pero teniendo 3 o mas tibbles para unirlas

Sera que si se puede unir las tibbles como se dijo anteiormente en el apartado *"Y lo que se quiere como resultado es"* poderlas trabajar?

Gracias

Answer (score 4):

Bienvenido/ Davitz,

Lo que buscas es unir las columnas y es bastante fácil. Dado que son objetos de la clase `tibble` seguramente estás usando las librerías  `dplyr` o `tidyverse`. En ese caso cuentas con la función `bind_cols()` que recibe como argumentos dos o más tibbles o `data.frame` (son prácticamente lo mismo) y los une creando una estructura más "ancha".

Va ejemplo:

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble1 <- tibble(a = 1:10, 
                  b = letters[1:10])
tibble2 <- tibble(c = 11:20, 
                  d = letters[11:20])
tibble3 <- tibble(e = 21:30, 
                  f = LETTERS[1:10])
tibble4 <- tibble(g = 31:45, 
                  h = LETTERS[11:25]) # Tiene 15 filas!

# Funciona porque todos los tibble tienen el mismo número de filas 
bind_cols(tibble1, tibble2, tibble3)

# Si el número de filas no es igual se produce un error
bind_cols(tibble1, tibble2, tibble3, tibble4)
```

Como se ve en el último ejemplo, es necesario que todos los `data.frame` o `tibble` tengan el mismo número de filas.

La función base `cbind()` hace lo mismo, pero a veces hace demasiado. Lo que ocurre con `cbind()` (y con otras funciones base similares) es que tienen unas reglas de coerción internas bastantes intrincadas cuando las ponemos a unir estructuras heterogéneas y a veces es difícil de predecir el tipo de output que vas a tener. Las funciones del `tidyverse` tienden a ser más consistentes en el output esperado y dar errores cuando algo no se cumple.

Ejemplo 2:

```
matriz <- matrix(1:100, ncol = 10)

#Produce un data.frame, aun cuando ninguna de las estructuras que lo forman es estrictamente un data.frame
cbind(tibble1, matriz)

#Produce un error, porque intenta crear un tibble, pero al no encontrar nombres de columna en `matriz` falla
bind_cols(tibble1, matriz)
```

Personalmente prefiero un error explícito a una función que intenta resolver los problemas con reglas de coerción y nos da un output que podría implicar un error silencioso. En tu caso las dos darían el mismo resultado.